# Flexbox sizing doesn't work correctly when using FontAwesome

Tags: html, css, flexbox, font-awesome

I am faceing very strange behaviour of flexbox for my page layout.I am using FontAwesome to render certain symbols.

Basically, **I have 2 flexbox items inside another flexbox item, and these child items render wider than parent item.**

1) I have a `.content__header` object, which is rendered as a flexbox object inside another series of flexbox objects.

2)The `.content__header` object contains 2 child objects: `.breadcrumb` and `.page_tools`. These child objects are rendered as flex items as well.

3) Inside the `.breadcrumb` object, I have some `span` objects (`.breadcrumb__test`) who's content is replaced by a [FontAwesome](https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) icon. The replacement is done using absolute positioning of the `::after` pseudo-element.

4) **When I remove all `.breadcrumb__text` HTML elements or just remove the `.breadcrumb__text::after` definition from my stylesheet - which defines the use of the FontAwesome font - the child objects (`.breadcrumb` and `.page_tools`) render at their correct width.** So I guess it has something to do with the replacement by a FontAwesome icon.

```
.breadcrumb__text::after {
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  font-weight: 400;
}
```

---

## Visual representation of the issue

The green line indicates the difference between the parent width and it's actual contents.

[image: Visual representation of the issue]

Code & Fiddle below.

**Browser:** Google Chrome 47.0.2526.106 m

---

## Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/44gymmw2/6/

---

## Update

When I remove `text-indent: 100%;` from the `.breadcrumb__text` CSS definition, the `.breadcrumb` renders as intended. However, when I leave the `text-indent` in place, and remove the `.breadcrumb__text::after` definition at the top of the style sheet (as described above), it also renders correctly.

Might this issue have something to do with the either FontAwesome or `text-indent` and flexbox?

---

## Code

**HTML**

```
<body>

  <div class="layout_wrapper">

    <div class="layout_container__content">
      <div class="content">
        <header class="content__header">

          <div class="breadcrumb">
            <span class="breadcrumb__text  breadcrumb__text--first">From </span><a class="breadcrumb__link" href="#">Dashboard</a><span class="breadcrumb__text"> to </span><a class="breadcrumb__link" href="#">Find records</a><span class="breadcrumb__text"> to </span>
            <h1 class="breadcrumb__current">Kylo Ren’s Command Shuttle™</h1>
          </div>

          <ul class="page_tools">
            <li class="page_tools__item">
              <button type="button" class="button  button--primary">Save</button>
            </li>
            <li class="page_tools__item">
              <button type="button" class="button">Cancel</button>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </header>

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="layout_container__sidebar">

      <div class="sidebar">
        <article class="widget">
          <h2 class="widget__title">Widget</h2>
        </article>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
/* Removing this makes it work */
.breadcrumb__text::after {
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  font-weight: 400;
}

/* Don't remove anything below */
.breadcrumb__text--first {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: -1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border: 0;
}

* {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}

html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.layout_wrapper {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.layout_container__content {
  flex: 0 0 75vw;
}

.layout_container__sidebar {
  flex: 0 0 25vw;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.content__header {
  outline: 1px solid blue;
  background-color: #434649;
  color: #ffffff;
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
}

.breadcrumb {
  outline: 3px dashed purple;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.breadcrumb__text {
  flex: 0 0 2em;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-indent: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.breadcrumb__text::after {
  content: '\f105';
  padding: 0;
  text-indent: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.breadcrumb__text--first {
  flex: 0 0 0;
}

.breadcrumb__text--first::after {
  content: none;
}

.breadcrumb__link {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 0.8571rem;
}

.breadcrumb__current {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.page_tools {
  outline: 3px dashed red;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  list-style: none outside none;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just finished reviewing your code and noticed the following:

- There are unnecessary (nested) flex containers (caused by using `display: flex;`).
- There are unnecessary flex-related declarations (just declaring the default behavior, such as `flex-flow: row no-wrap;` and `align-items: stretch`).
- There are several unnecessary declarations in the context of various unrelated selectors. Probably left-over declarations while testing / debugging.

That said, lets continue to your issue. It isn't obvious, so it needs some introduction.

[Pangloss](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34485256/5671829) introduces an important ingredient of your issue, which affects using `text-indent`. From [W3](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/text.html):

> The box is indented with respect to the left (or right, for right-to-left layout) edge of the line box. User agents must render this indentation as blank space.
>
> [...]
>
> If the value of `text-indent` is either negative or exceeds the width of the block, that first box, described above, can overflow the block. The value of `overflow` will affect whether such text that overflows the block is visible.

In other words: `text-indent` affects the dimensions of the box you apply it to.

You have declared `overflow: hidden;` on `.breadcrumb__text`. Obviously, for that declaration to have the desired effect, the box you applied it to needs a `width`, or else it wouldn't have a clipping edge.

`.breadcrumb__text` should get its width from the `flex-basis` declaration (specifically `flex: 0 0 2em;`) applied to it. Well... that's not happening, at least, not *entirely* as you would expect. Even though its width seems to be `2em`, for some reason it doesn't trigger the overflow behavior as it should. This seems to be a bug in the specific Chrome version you use, as its fixed in Canary (eg. version 49 and up).

So: this seems to be an issue with the flexbox implementation in Chrome. That said, with this knowledge, your issue can be fixed in multiple ways. Some examples:

#### `text-indent: -100%`

Using `text-indent: -100%` fixes your issue because it takes away the extra whitespace on the right side of the affected elements. (→ [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/peterslagter/44gymmw2/19/))

#### `width: 2em`

You could add the declaration `width: 2em` to `.breadcrumb__text`. That would fix the unexpected behavior of the `flex-basis` declaration. (→ [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/peterslagter/44gymmw2/20/))

#### `overflow: hidden;` on parent container

Adding `overflow: hidden;` on `.breadcrumbs` fixes your issue. Now the parent container has a clipping edge and handles the whitespace caused by using `text-indent: 100%`. (→ [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/peterslagter/44gymmw2/21/))

#### Final remarks

Flexbox is a powerful layout mode and it sure is great to experiment with. But, the algorithms are complex and browser implementations aren't free from issues yet. Make sure you take this into account when using flexbox.

Another concern when looking at your code is the way you use flexbox. Flexbox is there for you to use, but it doesn't necessarily have to replace every other way of dealing with layout. `display: inline-block;` or `display: table;`, or even `float` might do the job without introducing the complexity of nested flex containers.

Comment: Pesla beat me to writing an answer, but I came to the exact same conclusion. As an addition to the answer, the original code in the question works in Firefox, so it does seem like a Chrome bug. This is a great answer containing both an explanation to what is wrong, how to fix it, why it behaves the way it does and on top of that some great general advice on your code. Should be marked as correct.

Comment: Good answer indeed l, but just 1 thing remains unanswered: why does it work when I don't declare the use of FontAwesome, so the font in the after element is the default. Do missing glyphs have no width?

Comment: @GerritBertier It has width, [quick demo](https://jsfiddle.net/oxah8yz9/) a square placeholder. Unless you set it to `content: ""` then it has no size by default.

Comment: Nothing related to FontAwesome but `text-indent` is the killer for me here!

Answer (score 3):

The FontAwesome typeface isn't the root cause.  It's the H1 "block" layout definition set by default in your browser. Add this style to your breadcrumb__current class. See https://jsfiddle.net/44gymmw2/9/

```
 word-wrap:break-word
```

The H1 tag is a block level element, which will make it push the contents of that block across the entire page.  One other fix would be to change that from block to inline, like so:

```
h1 { display: inline; }
```

Or you could wrap that text in another element, like a span.

Comment: But why is it pushing that box over? The text isn't too long for the box. Also, why does it work when I remove the `.breadcrumb__text::after` from the stylesheet? By the way, your first Fiddle shows the same behaviour as described in my question.

Comment: @GerritBertier, The H1 tag gets displayed as a block level element by default, which makes the browser try to make that element span the entire width of that space.  You can alter that behavior by setting the H1 to display inline, like so:  h1 { display: inline; }.  That would also fix this problem.

Comment: I just edited the answer. Removed that fiddle and provided more clarification on the H1.  Good luck!

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't cut it. I set the `.breadcrumb__current` to `display: inline;`, but the issue persists (see https://jsfiddle.net/44gymmw2/10/). I found that the issue no longer occurs when removing the `.breadcrumb__text` elements. So it has something to do with those or their replacement using the `::after` pseudo-elements.

Comment: @GerritBertier, I see it working in FireFox and Chrome.   I was using the Chrome inspection tools on that.  It's probably some combination of factors.  Wish I had more time to help you out this morning, but I've got to keep working on something else.

Comment: If I toggle the `display:inline` on `.breadcrumb__current` on and off a few times in my Fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/44gymmw2/10/) using the Chrome inspector, it behaves even stranger. The `.breadcrumb` block becomes wider and wider. Thanks for trying though!

Comment: Yep, I noticed that in Chrome inspector on Fiddle as well.  You've got the original source, so outside Fiddle you can play with it there. You're welcome.

Comment: Similar behaviour outside the Fiddle as well, it has to do with the Chrome Inspector and rendering. However, like I said, the issue persists, also in my local source code. (btw: this is my last comment in this commen thread, if needed we can move to chat)

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is caused by the `text-indent:100%` rule, that added extra space on the right hand.

> The `text-indent` property specifies how much horizontal space should
>   be left before the beginning of the first line of the text content of
>   an element. **`<percentage>` value relative to the containing block
>   width**. -[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-indent)

See this simple demo:

```css
body {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
span {
  text-indent: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<span>text</span>
```

In your example, you can just change `text-indent:100%` to `text-indent:-9999px`, it works similarly, and it won't create the overflow.

**[Updated jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/44gymmw2/15/)**

Comment: But then why does this not occur when I remove the .breadcrumb__text::after CSS rule?

Comment: Your example code is rather complicated, one thing to consider is - pseudo element `::after` adds content inside the parent container, just before closing, and it indeed effects the content flow.

Comment: But I'm not setting the content property in that css rule, only the font family and weight...

Comment: You do have `content: '\f105';` set there. I also noticed the issue always has a delay to appear, I think it's the loading time wait for font awesome to apply.

Comment: Thats not the rule you have to remove, see the 1st css rule with comment above. Even of I set the content, it works fine not using FontAwesome...

Comment: My updated fiddle works, right? and I think it's an easy solution. I wish there is more I can help to find what exactly causes the issue, obviously it won't be easy, well good luck. I would re-write the html and css completely with a simpler approach if I were you, rather than trying hard to find the bug.

Answer (score 1):

Try witn inline-block property it is working good.

```
.content {
  display:inline-block;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: stretch;
}
```